# Gets invalid pointer to the interface from CoCreateInstance

Tags: c++, c, windows

`coInitializeExProc` and `coCreateInstanceProc` are pointers to the functions.

I get `S_OK` from the `coCreateInstanceProc` function, but my interface pointer `output->enumerator` is null. What is wrong here?

```
HRESULT hr;
hr = SUCCEEDED(coInitializeExProc(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED));

hr = coCreateInstanceProc(CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator,0,CLSCTX_ALL,IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator,(LPVOID*)&output->enumerator);

hr = output->enumerator->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eRender,eConsole,&output->endPointDevice);
```

Comment: Oh I forgot add SUCCEEDED macro. Now code is S_FALSE. But why if it is not listed as code for coCreateInstance

Comment: You wrap the COM functions and interface pointers in your own code, it's hard to tell from here whether those wrappers are buggy. Try vanilla CoCreateInstance and a vanilla interface pointer, see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Oh, and CoInitializeEx returns S_FALSE if it was already called. That's not an error.